# Copy output of npm install to docker container

Tags: node.js, dockerfile, npm-install

I dockerized node.js and all works fine

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

I'm trying to run `npm install` outside Dockerfile and to copy content of `npm install` to docker container

On docker host i ran

```
npm install --prefix /opt/npm/ -g
```

Folder `/opt/npm/lib/node_modules/ui` is created. In that folder there are bunch json files and folder node_modules.Dockerfile is in that foler.Now, in Dockerfile i skipped npm install and just copied content of /opt/npm/lib/node_modules/ui to docker container.

Modified Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY . .
EXPOSE 9000
```

Built image from Dockerfile sucessfully, but when trying to run container from that image

docker run -p 9000:4200 pm

```
> ui@0.0.0 dev /app
> ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config src/proxy.conf.json

sh: ng: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! ui@0.0.0 dev: `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config src/proxy.conf.json`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ui@0.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

Is it possible to run `npm install` outside docker container ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When dockerizing any application you should always compile and install dependencies in the docker container.

Your Docker file start form `node:alpine`. this means that when you install an npm package that needs compilation outside (your OS) the alpine OS won't be able to use this.

Best practice is to always build your application on the same OS. That's way docker introduce build container.

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:12.13-alpine As build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=production


FROM node:12.13-alpine as production

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./ ./ # copy static files
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/node_modules ./. # Copy node_modules from build container

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "main.js"]
```

```
# .dockerignore
node_modules
Dockerfile
```

Try to fit this to your environment